# Error: Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Running flutter build apk --release shows me the following error:

```
     [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                              
     Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, 
     then update
     C:\Users\jmichelena\Desktop\Buenas\hola\android\build.gradle:                                       
     ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

I already updated the version of kotlin in the arvhico buil.grade but it keeps showing me the same error

```
                                                buildscript {
                                                ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
                                                repositories {
                                                    google()
                                                    mavenCentral()
                                                }
```

Comment: did you clean your project?

Comment: yes, I already ran flutter clean several times